# PTIJ: Fibonacci Numbers - Mi Yodeya?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

### Who knows Fibonacci numbers?

### מספר פיבונצ'י - מי יודע

From Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, the Fibonacci numbers are the numbers in the following
> integer sequence, called the Fibonacci sequence, and characterized by
> the fact that every number after the first two is the sum of the two
> preceding ones. Such as:

1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34...

The first two numbers are defined as 1 and 1.

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). I was able to find something interesting about the first two numbers, but nothing Jewishly related regarding the number sequence. Maybe you can add things up and come up with something ;-)

Please, no lazy gematria about these numbers. I'm looking for something clever.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated).

Comment: Hey, don't take @IsaacMoses' job! ;) +1 for the good post.

Comment: @ezra I wouldn't think of it. I'm just following up on what I did last year regarding irrational numbers - Mi Yodeya.

Comment: For serious answers, see here https://www.google.ca/search?safe=active&client=opera&hs=wJx&ei=H1mLWqqoPIjijwTU8piICQ&q=fibonacci+torah&oq=fibonacci+torah&gs_l=psy-ab.3...115396.119581.0.119875.17.12.1.4.4.0.156.1077.8j3.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.13.868...0j0i131k1j0i10k1.0.UGsdRDwdQWY

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as Purim Torah under the policy

Comment: @DoubleAA We have one last year regarding irrational numbers. How is this different?

Comment: @danf how is this absurd or making fun? I'd be genuinely interested to see use of the Fibonacci numbers in Judaism. Asking about irrational numbers is absurd since there are so many of them. Imo.

Comment: Hmm  let's see - the first "1" is Hashem, He made the next "1"Adam, then Eve made it "2"(or maybe their two children), after the murder but before Seth they were down to only "3", Cain left, so Seth and his wife and Enosh made it a total of "5".  Add back the distant Cain and his wife and Enoch and there's "8"(phooey, there's gotta be a better way!), five more generations until Methuselah, that's a "13"...running out of stuff here....Enoch  begets Methuselah in Chapter 5, Verse "21"...yeah, enough....

Comment: @DoubleAA "Asking about irrational numbers is absurd since there are so many of them. Imo." Your point is that irrational numbers exist in a different degree of infinity than Fibonacci numbers, and therefore this question should be closed?

Comment: @DanF מי יודע סדרת פיבונאצ'י ? Rambam apparently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_mean_(Judaism)

Comment: @DanF Also: A bunch of sites from the cult of the ratio phi assert that the Ark of the Covenant and the Ark of the Flood were both golden rectangles. Can  anyone confirm or deny?
x

Comment: @sah no. As I understand it this isn't a question about numbers which are Fibonacci numbers but rather about the set of them. So a fact about the number 8 won't work here, whereas a fact about the number e will work at the other question.

Answer (score 2):

From *Midrash [Kepler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Kepler)* 15:71:

> How was the עגל הזהב created? First, Aaron took 3 earrings, and melted them into 2 pieces; then he took [enough to have collected] 5 earrings, and melted them into 3 pieces; then he took [enough to have collected] 8 earrings, and melted them into 5 pieces; and so he continued until there were no more earrings to collect.

The traditional commentators are puzzled by this *midrash*.  Of course, it's clear that if there had been an unlimited supply of earrings, [this would eventually produce זהב](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence).  But there was only a finite supply of earrings!

Finally, the [Taz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_HaLevi_Segal) answered that the finiteness of the earrings is why it's called the עגל הזהב: it was close enough to [round off](http://www.morfix.co.il/%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%92%D7%9C).